# Ford E150 1994 stalling rough idling and shaking

Tags: ford, stall, rough-idle, van

Having an issue with a Ford E150 1994 van . The issue is that the van stalls , has rough idle and shakes a lot. once the gear is put into drive. I tried a few things
I replaced the air intake control valve with a new one
I cleaned the EGR with cleaner
I cleaned the throttle body with throttle body cleaner spray

The issue persists and once a load is added eg. turn the wheels all the way, turn on the ac, put the van into drive. Please assist. When started it runs like a wounded beast.

I'm getting error codes 412, 121 and 538

Comment: Have checked / replaced the plugs? checked coils? when was it last serviced?

Comment: Not yet . Ill check coil and replace spark plugs

Comment: I have idea when it was last serviced